# Different search results with Twitter4j and twitter.com

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j for searching tweets.  But the results returned are very different from the ones that are returned on the website.

Should I not expect the results to be nearly same? The code that I am using is the same as shown in their code examples page:

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
Query query = new Query("Halloween");
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() 
        + ":" + status.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The api doc http://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search says.

> "The Twitter Search API is part of Twitter's v1.1 REST API. It allows
>   queries against the indices of recent or popular Tweets and behaves
>   similarily to, but not exactly like the Search feature available in
>   Twitter mobile or web clients, such as Twitter.com search."

So you might expect the API to behave differently. That's Okay :)

Also see this FAQ : [Why are the Tweets I'm looking for not in Twitter Search, the Search API, or Search widgets?](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#8650)